# How to check Bad request for @Min on request param in spring controller?

Tags: spring, rest, unit-testing, mockmvc

I am pretty new to spring controller. I am trying to write unit test for invalid parameter. I have an api that has @RequestParam("id") @Min(1) long id and in my unit test, I pass in "-1". Here is my test:

```
@Test
    public void searchWithInvalidIbId() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URL)
            .param(COLUMN_IB_ID, INVALID_IB_ID_VALUE) // = "-1"
            .param(COLUMN_TIME_RANGE, TIME_RANGE_VALUE)
            .param(COLUMN_TIME_ZONE, TIME_ZONE_VALUE)
            .accept(PowerShareMediaType.PSH_DISPATCH_REPORTER_V1_JSON)
            .contentType(PowerShareMediaType.PSH_DISPATCH_REPORTER_V1_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
```

When I run this, I get

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: search.arg2: must be greater than or equal to 1
```

It makes sense, but I am not sure how to test this is BadRequest. I tried @Test(expected = NestedServletException.class), and it passed, but I don't think it is checking what I want to check. What is the right approach to check this?

Comment: Are you handle `ConstraintViolationException` in ExceptionHandler ?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem @Jonathon Hagen? If so, you can mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can have your custom exception handler annotated with **@ControllerAdvice** and handle **ConstraintViolationException** in that class. You can throw your custom exception with additional details if you wish.

Here is an example approach:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyCustomExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    ApiError constraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        return BAD_REQUEST.apply(e.getBindingResult());
    }
}
```

Here **ApiError** is a custom class to represent your error response, it can be anything else you want. You can add timestamp, http status, your error message etc.

Comment: We decided to halt on this issue so I wasn't able to test this. I will check it once I come back to this issue. Still thanks!